# Replace Space with Newline in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to create a new line after each `<li>` element.  I stripped the `<li>` of spaces using `/\s*<li>/g`, but it's not working like I want it to work.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jthN/19/).

For example:

Processing this text using `doIt(){...}`

```
<ol>
 <li>Hello world! :)</li> 
  <li>Hello how are you</li> 
   <li>good</li>
</ol>
```

I used `/\s*<li>/g` to remove **any amount of** space before `<li>`, and it gives you:

```
1. Hello world! :)2. Hello how are you3. good
```

Is there a way to make the above, look like:

```
1. Hello world! :)
2. Hello how are you
3. good
```

Here is `doIt(){...}`

```
function doIt() {
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var olPatt = /<ol>\s*((?:<li>.+<\/li>\s*)+)<\/ol>/g;
var i = 1;

input.value = input.value.replace(olPatt, function (n, listItems) {
    return listItems.replace(/\s*<li>/g, function() {return i++ + '.' + ' ';}).replace(/<\/li>/g, '');
});

input.value = input.value.replace(ulPatt, function (n, listItems) {
    return listItems.replace(/\s*<li>/g, function () {
    return i++ + '.' + ' ';
    }).replace(/<\/li>/g, '');
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fiddle code,

replace your this line ,
return listItems.replace(/\s*

/g, function() {return i++ + '.' + ' ';}).replace(/</li>/g, '');

by this line,
return listItems.replace(/\s*

/g, function() {return i++ + '.' + ' ';}).replace(/</li>/g, '\n')

It will give you line break after 1, 2 & 3...

Comment: Yeah, haha just figured that out while I was waiting xD  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

LOL fixed it.

I need to apply `'\n'` to `.replace(/<\/li>/g, '\n');`

```
input.value = input.value.replace(olPatt, function (n, listItems) {
    return listItems.replace(/\s*<li>/g, function() {return i++ + '.' + ' ';}).replace(/<\/li>/g, '\n');
});
```